# how do I bring up "Are you sure you want to leave page?" popup in vue.js router?

Tags: vue.js, popup, router

I'm building a vue.js application. We'd like to have a popup come up when the user attempts to leave a specific page. The popup should say "Are you sure you want to leave the page?" I know I can implement something in the beforeRouteLeave hook of the component, but I'm wondering if there's a way to implement this in the beforeEach event of the router (i.e. not the component). The reason I'd like to use the router is because beforeEach in the router seems to respond to the user entering a different path in the browser url bar, whereas the beforeRouteLeave hook on the component does not. However, I don't have access to the popup in the router whereas I do in the component (the popup would just be part of the template).

So the question is: how can I bring up a popup in the router before the user actually leaves the page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you can assign a name for each of your routes objects in routes array inside your router or another field like requiredConfirmation or something like that, imagine that we have a routes like this :

```
routes : [
    {
    path : '/needconfirm',
    component : NeedConfirmToLeaveCom,
    name : 'needconfirm-route1'
  },
    {
    path : '/neednotconfirm',
    component : NeedNotConfirmToLeaveCom,
    name : 'normal-route1'
  },
]
```

then you can use `router.beforeEach` to set some conditions or some confirmations based on your Origin route and Destination route.
something like this :

```
router.beforeEach((to,from,next) => {
  if(from.name.startsWith("needconfirm-")) {
    if(window.confirm("Are you sure you want to leave the page?")) {
      next();
    }
  }else next();
});
```

UPDATE * :
if you want to use some custom components for your popup, you can use vuex to store your component's logic and toggler and import that component in your App.Vue or other root/child components you wish. because you have access to your store management using `$store` right?

UPDATE ** :
and one other thing i want to mention, if you want to save some progress or state and because of that you want to get confirmation from user (progress will lost if they switch route), you should consider using Vuex to store your progress or state of your application and if you want more persisted solution you can use VuexPersisted store management which uses LocalStorage.

[Vue router navigation guards document](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

[Vuex Doc](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `beforeunload` event listener on the main component in that view.

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Depending on the browser, it will show the popup with default values populated.

This is how I use it in the `created` hook of the main component

```
 window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // chrome requires returnValue to be set
    const message = "You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you wish to leave?"
    e.returnValue = message
    return message
})
```